# Python Heun finite differences

Tags: python

Problem:
[image]

I have that problem to do with python, I am trying to apply heun's method, but it throws me the error "'Add' object is not callable"

I attach code and how I am applying it

```
def metodo_Heun(f,alpha,a,b,N):
  W = np.zeros(N+1)
  h = (b-a)/N
  tiempos = np.linspace(a,b,N+1)
  W[0] = alpha
  for i in range(N):
    W[i+1] = W[i] + 0.25*h*f(tiempos[i],W[i]) + 0.75*h*f(tiempos[i]+(2*h/3),W[i]+(2*h/3)*f(tiempos[i]+(h/3),W[i]+(h/3)*f(tiempos[i],W[i])))
  return tiempos, W
```

```
def fx2(x):
    return (((-q*l)/(2*D)*x) + ((q/(2*D)*x**2)) + ((S/D)) * W)
```

```
q =200
l = 50
D = 8.8*10**7
S = 100
```

```
metodo_Heun(fx2(x),0, 1,49 , 49 )
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-e730d1163165> in <module>()
----> 1 metodo_Heun(fx2(x),0, 1,49 , 49 )

<ipython-input-52-013dc30c361a> in metodo_Heun(f, alpha, a, b, N)
     23   for i in range(N):
---> 24     W[i+1] = W[i] + 0.25*h*f(tiempos[i],W[i]) + 0.75*h*f(tiempos[i]+(2*h/3),W[i]+(2*h/3)*f(tiempos[i]+(h/3),W[i]+(h/3)*f(tiempos[i],W[i])))
     25   return tiempos, W

TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about your approach to solving the problem? How are you calculating the differential equation?

Comment: sure based on the book Numerical Analysis (10th Edition)

mentions that I must approximate the deflection of W (x) for every 1 inch using the finite difference method, where leaving the second derivative of W alone on the left side = S / D * W - (ql / 2D) * x + ( q / 2D) * x ^ 2 where w (0) and w (l) = 0 would be the initial conditions.
by transferring and replacing the values, it remains that h = 1 and N = 49. 
sorry if my english is bad :(

Answer (score 1):

You evaluate the function `fx2`, but in the function `metodo_heun` you try to call this function. You should pass the function (not its evaluation) to `metodo_heun`:

```
metodo_Heun(fx2, 0, 1,49, 49)
```

BTW `fx2` gets two inputs (`x` & `W`) and other parameters stay fixed. Thus, you should change our function signature to `fx2(x, W)`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for you answer.
i tried what you mentioned
but appear the same error, 


In this case, how could this function be passed to the heun method?
I tried but "Add 'object is not callable" still appears. Maybe the def method_heun that I did is wrongly posed for the problem?

Comment: How do you call the heun method?

Comment: is this def metodo_Heun(f,alpha,a,b,N): 

the exercise asks to resolve out the problem using the heun method (to solve systems of 2 equations)

Comment: Not why, but how do you call the function in code? There is still some issue on how you call this function. You should call the function like this `metodo_Heun(fx2, 0, 1,49, 49)` and change the function signature, i.e.,  `def fx2(x,W): ...` instead of `def fx2(x): ...`

Comment: I just did what you tell me and it gave me results, one more query. How could I know if the data that it gave me in the array is correct?

sorry for so much question. Well, according to the book I'm seeing, the result seems to be other.  the book is numerical analysis 10th edition, chaptar 11.3 problem 8E

Comment: I guess, your implementation should just follow Algorithm 11.3 in the book. I'd suggest to just follow their pseudocode. Also carefully check the boundaries a,b whether they are included or excluded. For testing your function, you could just use the provided examples

Comment: I checked it, but since I don't know anything about maple, I wouldn't know how to transcribe it to python, sorry for my many questions sir